# How to propose for the P.hd Scholar in part-time?

Tags: discussion

I have completed my M.Sc Information Technology (5 years integrated) from Anna University on 2012. I'm interested in Higher Studies. 
Whether i have to go for the MS/P.hd, Where could i search. For my Qualification what could i propose..

I'm new to this, anybody give me some suggestions, Please..

Comment: Tell me some way to approach for Phd

Comment: http://www-2.cs.cmu.edu/~harchol/gradschooltalk.pdf

Answer (score 3):

1. This forum is for discussions pertaining to the management of the main site on theoretical computer science
2. Your question has nothing to do with theoretical computer science and is off scope
3. You might consider browsing the questions on academia.stackexchange.com. I wouldn't post your question there, because it's too specific for that site as well.